# Ubuntu Server 20.04 - MDNS queries respond to a unique device

Tags: networking, server, avahi, mdns

I'm trying to set up a MDNS reflector in Ubuntu Server 20.04 between 2 vlans but I need that a device connected to the first vlan get the address of a device connected to the other vlan. For example if I have in vlan 10 two mobile phones and in vlan 20 have 2 Chromecasts I need that each mobile phones get the address off an unique chromecast. Is it possible to do that with some package like avahi?

Best regards,

Comment: You have made no mention of any Ubuntu OS in this question. Only thing you describe is off topic hardware.

Answer (score 0):

there is need to have configuration item to make two or more VLANs communicable for Avahi. you (most probably) will need to configure firewalls on all sides too.

this item in configuration should solve your problem

```
[reflector]
enable-reflector=yes
```

more details available from [here](https://blog.christophersmart.com/2020/03/30/resolving-mdns-across-vlans-with-avahi-on-openwrt/)